# Error while compiling asp.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

When I compile my asp.net application,I get the below mentioned error.This error occurs often.The language I am using C#.

> Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 03976102): likely
>   culprit is 'BEGIN'

Comment: Are you running an RC or can you post some code?

Comment: @deep: when you get an error like this, search for exact error message in Google..You will find lots of possibilities for that error and possible fixes..

Answer (score 1):

I found some information about the error on the [Microsoft connect site](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534059/error-cs0583-internal-compiler-error-0xc0000005-at-address-3eac16a1-likely-culprit-is-begin)

An excerpt from the page is as follows :

> I believe that this issue has been fixed post-RC. The problem is that
>   the C# compiler is crashing as it is tries to report an error or
>   warning. In several cases we have seen the warning being reported is
>   that the LIB environment variable contains an invalid path. To avoid
>   the crash, check that your LIB environment variable contains valid
>   paths.